# Distribute python code with python inside to avoid installation

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller

I have built a bundled Python application that is a composition of an installed (i.e. "`*.exe`", via `pyinstaller`) and a code (i.e. "`*.py`") part. This is due to a package that does not support installation, thus I have to call it directly from source.

I am able to distribute and run the application by including in the bundle my environment in `.\venv` and running the code via `.\venv\Scripts\python.exe my_script.py`, however it requires Python installed onto the machine, raising an Error otherwise

```
No Python at 'C:\Python38\python.exe'
```

Is there a way to include `Python38` folder in my package to allow anyone to start the application regardless of Python installed or not (and its version)? I've tried to:

- copy `Python38` folder within package and within `.\venv\Scripts\` hoping that `.\venv\Scripts\python.exe` was searching there before looking in `C:\` -> *not working*
- include `Python38` in my package and force its copy in `C:\` as the very first instruction -> *it works, but it seems like cheating, and it may mess up things on recipient's computer*

Comment: My usual approach is to use pip freeze in these cases. Have you looked into that? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_freeze/

Comment: `pip freeze` allows to recreate the environment using `pip`, but my use case is for a computer that does not have python installed, and then `pip` neither

Comment: how about converting it to an exe file? https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: As I mentioned, I have converted to exe some parts of the application, but some modules do not support it, thus requiring to call source directly.

Comment: Yes, it is possible and the way you do it is the way you describe.... The problem with doing this is it will dramatically inflate the size of the executable file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem in a somehow easy way:

- include `Python38` in my package together with my `venv` (obviously, they cause the destination folder to grow in size, but it is not a big issue for my purposes)
- update `.\venv\pyvenv.cfg` changing from absolute path to Python on my computer to a relative path inside the destination folder

Here a reference to the updated `pyvenv.cfg`:

```
home = .\Python38                          <-- updated: it was "C:\Python38"
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.8.5.final.0
virtualenv = 20.4.7
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = .\Python38                   <-- updated
base-exec-prefix = .\Python38              <-- updated
base-executable = .\Python38\python.exe    <-- updated
```

FYI, here the code I used to automatically update the `pyvenv.cfg`, that works with different python versions and paths:

```
import os
import re
from configparser import ConfigParser

# Set original and updated config paths
venv_cfg = 'pyvenv.cfg'
in_venv_cfg = os.path.join('.', 'venv', venv_cfg)
out_venv_cfg = os.path.join('.', 'config', venv_cfg)  # changing folder to avoid override of venv config

# Parse data in config
with open(in_venv_cfg, 'r') as f:
    config_lines = f.readlines()
config = ConfigParser()
config.read_string('[cfg]\n' + ''.join(config_lines))

# Get python version and location
py_path = config.get('cfg', 'home')
py_dir, py_name = os.path.dirname(py_path), os.path.basename(py_path)

# Update paths to python and save venv configuration
new_config_lines = [re.sub(r'(=\s*)' + py_dir.replace("\\", r"\\") + f'({py_name})', r'\1.\\\2', line) for line in config_lines]
with open(out_venv_cfg, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_config_lines)
```